# redirect to HTML page using spring boot / thymyleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class GraphController {

    @GetMapping("/displayBarGraph")
    public String barGraph(Model model) {
        Map<String, Integer> surveyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        surveyMap.put("Java", 40);
        surveyMap.put("Dev oops", 25);
        surveyMap.put("Python", 20);
        surveyMap.put(".Net", 15);
        model.addAttribute("surveyMap", surveyMap);
        return "barGraph";
    }

    @GetMapping("/displayPieChart")
    public String pieChart(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("pass", 50);
        model.addAttribute("fail", 50);
        return "pieChart";
    }
```

This is my `file.proprieties`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

Those are my HTML files:

[image]

but it always redirect me like this:

[image]

Any solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Setting `spring.thymeleaf.enabled` to `false` disables Thymeleaf for Spring MVC/Web. Therefore, the controller just returns the name of the Thymeleaf template instead of going through the Thymeleaf view resolution.

   To solve this, remove the `spring.thymeleaf.enabled` property or set it to `true` which is the [default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/47516b50c39bd6ea924a1f6720ce6d4a71088651/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafProperties.java#L113) for Thymeleaf auto-configuration:

   ```
   spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
   ```
2. Use `@Controller` instead of `@RestController` when working with a templating engine and you don't want the return value to be bound to the response body:

   ```java
   @Controller
   public class GraphController {

       @GetMapping("/displayBarGraph")
       public String barGraph(Model model) {
           // ...
           return "barGraph";
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Your configured template path needs to match the actual path where the templates are stored. So either change set`spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/template/` **or** rename the `template` directory to `templates`.
4. Remove the two properites `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix` from your configuration. This would be necessary if you want to use JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of changes to make this work.

1. **Change @RestController to @Controller so that it returns page instead of response in the body.**
2. Rename folder to templates or change the path in properties file for view resolver.
3. no need of thymeleaf enabled property.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your

`src/main/resources/template`

folder to

`src/main/resources/templates`

You are missing "s" in the folder name.